# No conceptual Schema with Entity Framework 6

Tags: entity-framework

i I'm using the last version of Entity Framework 6.0.2 with a .net 4.0 website and Model First approach. Everything works OK in my local machine but when upload the site to my webserver I get a Parser error.

Parser Error Message: No Conceptual Schema node to embed as a resource
Source Error: 
[No relevant source lines]

Source File:  /App_Code/SMSModel.edmx    Line:  0

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <edmx:Edmx Version="3.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
      <!-- EF Runtime content -->
      <edmx:Runtime>
        <!-- SSDL content -->
        <edmx:StorageModels>
          <Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl" Namespace="Model.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ProviderManifestToken="2005">
            <EntityContainer Name="ModelTargetContainer" >
            </EntityContainer>
          </Schema>
        </edmx:StorageModels>
        <!-- CSDL content -->
        <edmx:ConceptualModels>
          <Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm" xmlns:cg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/codegeneration" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" Namespace="Model" Alias="Self" xmlns:annotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" annotation:UseStrongSpatialTypes="false">
            <EntityContainer Name="ModelContainer" annotation:LazyLoadingEnabled="true">
              <EntitySet Name="Companies" EntityType="Model.Company" />
            </EntityContainer>
            <EntityType Name="Company">
              <Key>
                <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
              </Key>
              <Property Name="Id" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
            </EntityType>
          </Schema>
        </edmx:ConceptualModels>
        <!-- C-S mapping content -->
        <edmx:Mappings>
          <Mapping xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/mapping/cs" Space="C-S">
            <Alias Key="Model" Value="Model" />
            <Alias Key="Target" Value="Model.Store" />
            <EntityContainerMapping CdmEntityContainer="ModelContainer" StorageEntityContainer="ModelTargetContainer">
            </EntityContainerMapping>
          </Mapping>
        </edmx:Mappings>
      </edmx:Runtime>
      <!-- EF Designer content (DO NOT EDIT MANUALLY BELOW HERE) -->
      <edmx:Designer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
        <edmx:Connection>
          <DesignerInfoPropertySet>
            <DesignerProperty Name="MetadataArtifactProcessing" Value="EmbedInOutputAssembly" />
          </DesignerInfoPropertySet>
        </edmx:Connection>
        <edmx:Options>
          <DesignerInfoPropertySet>
            <DesignerProperty Name="ValidateOnBuild" Value="true" />
            <DesignerProperty Name="EnablePluralization" Value="True" />
            <DesignerProperty Name="CodeGenerationStrategy" Value="None" />
          </DesignerInfoPropertySet>
        </edmx:Options>
        <!-- Diagram content (shape and connector positions) -->
        <edmx:Diagrams>
        </edmx:Diagrams>
      </edmx:Designer>
    </edmx:Edmx>
```

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: The code from the edmx? Is too long. I edit my post with the first lines.

Comment: Need to see if the CSDL content section is present in the EDMX.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía Of course we only need relevant code, not all code.

Comment: I delete everything and now I have only one Entity and I get the same error. Now I post all edmx code.

Comment: I think Edmx Version="3.0" doesn't work with .NET 4. Now I started all over again and before installing EF 6 I created edmx file (with versión 2.0) and then I install (nuget) EF 6. Everything Works except I can't use enum.